# Promise.resolve() returns empty arrays that were populated using Array.push()

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, promise

I have this code in which I add users to the Firebase DB, and `resolve` the `Promise` when the user import is done. In the resolve, I include arrays which contain the users that were added. These arrays are populated when a single user is added. The code is below:

```
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let usersAdded = [];
    users.map((user, index) => {
        db.ref('/users').push(user, err => {
            if(!err) {
                usersAdded.push(user)
                console.log(`Array at iteration ${index}: ${usersAdded}`)
            }
            if(index == users.length-1){
              resolve({status: true, usersAdded})
            }
        })
    })
})
```

Console Output:

```
Array at iteration 0: [{name: nadir, email: iamnadir10@yahoo.com, creditCard: true}]
Array at iteration 1: [{name: nadir, email: iamnadir10@yahoo.com, creditCard: true}, {name: arslan, email: arslan346@yahoo.com, creditCard: true}]
Array at iteration 2: [{name: nadir, email: iamnadir10@yahoo.com, creditCard: true}, {name: arslan, email: arslan346@yahoo.com, creditCard: true}, {name: farhan, email: farhan1992@gmail.com, creditCard: true}]
```

Although when I see the response on `.then(user)`, it returns an empty array (`usersAdded`). Users get added in Firebase as well. Can anyone tell me what is the problem here?

Edit:

I was able to solve it, the problem was that the Promise was resolved before the db.ref.push triggered the callback, in that callback, I was populating the array, as it was an async operation.

Comment: Shouldn't you be calling `Promise.all` on an array of Promises if you want to iterate over all `users`?

Comment: You can only resolve a promise once.  Your code looks like it's trying to resolve a promise as many times as there are elements in `users`.  Not sure what you're intending here.

Comment: Hey, @DougStevenson glad you answered a big fan of you, as you can see I have an `if` statement in which the condition is only true when the loop is on the last iteration.

Comment: @CertainPerformance This Promise is inside a function, which function is called by another function. So when it is resolved on the last iteration of the loop, it should return the `usersAdded` array, which ten will be send to the user using `res.send()`

Comment: What you're doing will only work if the asynchronous `db.ref...push` executes serially - otherwise, there's no guarantee that the last item `push` is called with will be the last asynchronous operation to complete. Better to use `Promise.all`, though I'm not sure why the `usersAdded` result would be *empty*, I'd expect it to contain at least *one* item (unless there was an error, in which case you might want to `reject` - also avoid the explicit Promise construction antipattern)

Comment: is there anything in the `err` variable? I don't think it should return empty array. Maybe 1 element. But not empty. can you console.log the err?

Comment: @AritraChakraborty, I already logged the `err` variable, the output was `null`, so I don't think that can cause a problem.

Comment: Is there a chance `usersAdded` is resolved when the function is first read? The returned object would contain `usersAdded: []`. Can you try to do `usersAdded: usersAdded` instead?

Comment: @AmanuelNega I was able to solve it, the problem was that the Promise was resolved before the db.ref.push triggered the callback, in that callback, I was populating the array, as it was an async operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like [CertainPerformance said in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53664314/prmoise-resolve-return-empty-arrays-that-were-populated-using-array-push/53668426#comment94186487_53664314) your code only works assuming the *push* callbacks get called in order. Since they are most likely asynchronous the order of the callback execution is not guaranteed. **This means if the last *push* callback is called first you promise already resolves.** For this reason you should use [*Promise.all()*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) to wait until all the *push* callbacks are resolved then handle the results.

```
return Promise.all(users.map(user => {
    return new Promise(resolve => db.ref('/users').push(user, resolve));
}))
.then(pushResults => { // all push callbacks are resolved
    return pushResults
        .map((error, index) => error ? null : users[index])
        .filter(Boolean);
});
```

You might however want to call *reject* if none of the users successfully saved. This makes the code more complicated, but you can than use *catch* on the returned promise if no users where saved.

```
// return a resolved promise if the users array is empty
if (!users.length) return Promise.resolve(users);

// handle a non-empty users array
return Promise.all(users.map(user => {
    return new Promise(resolve => db.ref('/users').push(user, resolve));
}))
.then(pushResults => {
    // all users had errors
    if (pushResults.every(Boolean)) 
        return Promise.reject(pushResults);

    // one or multiple users had no errors
    return pushResults
        .map((error, index) => error ? null : users[index])
        .filter(Boolean);
});
```

Returning a value other than a promise inside a *then* function will simply be forwarded to the next *then* as if you returned `Promise.resolve(value)`.